# Get posts using WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, functions

I want to show posts using WP_Query functions. Also I want to add random order.

So I try

```
<?php
  $temp = $wp_query; 
  $wp_query= null;
  $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'rand',
  ); 
  $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
  $wp_query->query('showposts=8' . '&paged='.$paged );
  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
```

I can see 8 posts but it seems 'orderby' => 'rand' doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite some time since I worked with WordPress, but it seems to me that:

## You're executing the query twice.

- First when you pass `$args` to the constructor during instantiation.
- Second when you call `query()`.

**With this, you're essentially overwriting the first query (the one that contains the orderby=rand).**

The [documentation of WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) mentions that `get_posts()` is called if you use a parameter in the constructor, and it shouldn't be called twice:

> **&get_posts()** – Fetch and return the requested posts from the database.
>   Also populate $posts and $post_count. Note: **This is called during
>   construction if WP_Query is constructed with arguments.** It is not
>   idempotent and **should not be called more than once on the same query
>   object.** Doing so may result in a broken query.

And the `query()` method's documentation states that it calls `get_posts()`, therefore it's called twice:

> **&query( $query )** – **Call** parse_query() and **get_posts()**. Return the
>   results of get_posts().

## The solution:

- You should either put everything in `$args`, or
- add the `orderby` parameter too to the `$wp_query->query(..)` call.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the WP_Query class reference and work yourself up from there. Try the basic examples, play around with the parameters until you get a feel for how WP_Query and the loop works.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

The reason your query isn't working is that you are not passing the parameters correctly (use the args array for all) and using deprecated params.